# Массивы переменной длины C

Tags: c, компиляция

Файл oooo.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    int x[size];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) x[i] = i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) printf("%d", x[i]);
}
```

Собираю вот так: `gcc -std=c89 oooo.c`
Запускаю вот так: `gcc ./a.out 1000000` 
Почему это собирается и не падает, что происходит со стеком?

Comment: Это не может собраться, поскольку есть необъявленная переменная `size`.

Comment: поправил, copy/paste :(

Comment: Что именно в механизме `VLA` Вам не понятно?

Comment: Да собственно всЁ!. WTF???

Comment: При декларации такого динамического массива конец стека сдвигается. Компилятор же изначально размещает в текущем фрейме только дескрипторы таких массивов и модифицирует их, когда поток управления достигает декларации. Надеюсь, теперь идея ясна?

Comment: за кулисами производится вызов alloca?

Comment: @cipher_web, на будущее -- если хотите, чтобы конкретный человек увидел Ваш комментарий (он получает нотификацию на страничке ruSO), вставьте в его начале `@NICKNAME` (к сожалению, так можно оповесть только одного)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь используется механизм VLA (Variable Length Array).

Реализация VLA, как и то, где будет размещён массив, в куче или стеке,
зависит от компилятора. В GCC он будет размещён в стеке (естественно, что тут
не выполняется alloca, но с помощью alloca можно самому сымитировать VLA).

Что произойдёт, если размер масива окажется слишком большим для стека?
Поведение в этом случае не определено, и лучше его избегать.

Лучше использовать VLA только в тех случаях, когда потенциальные размеры
массивов заранее известны, и они не очень велики.

Здесь рассматривается, как можно избежать краха программы
при использовании VLA-массивов слишком большого размера:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151172/how-do-you-prevent-variable-length-arrays-from-crashing-when-there-is-not-enough (англ.)

Здесь рассматриваются преимущества и недостатки массивов VLA:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082126/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-c99-vla-compared-to-malloc-free (англ.)

Которые можно кратко обозначить как: простота, наглядность, threadsafety. Минусами явлюятся: ограничение по размеру, проблемы со стеком в случае чего (потенциальная небезопасность), ограниченная поддержка компиляторами.